# In Shiny I want to updateSelectInput() only once during UI load

Tags: r, shiny-server

I have a drop-down (SelectInput) that I want to update only once and load it up with a list of items programmatically during the upload of UI. I was putting it in a Render function but the problem is it resets again and again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selectInput` has parameters that allows you to set the initial state. Among these parameters, you can use `choices` for providing options and `selected` for having defaults. Please run `?shiny::selectInput` for additional details.

Rendering it in `server` side or preferably using `updateSelectInput` would be of help if you want to update it upon user interaction in a reactive context.

Here is a minimal example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput(
    inputId = "digits_input", 
    label = "Digits:", 
    choices = 0:9
    ## other arguments with default values:
    # selected = NULL,
    # multiple = FALSE,
    # selectize = TRUE, 
    # width = NULL, 
    # size = NULL
  ),

  selectInput(
    inputId = "letters_input", 
    label = "Lower case letters:", 
    choices = letters,
    selected = c("a", "b", "c"), # initially selected items 
    multiple = T # to be able to select multiple items
  ),

  actionButton(
    inputId = "update",
    label = "Capitalize"
  )

)

server <- function(session, input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$update, {
    updateSelectInput(
      session,
      inputId = "letters_input",
      label = "Upper case letters:",
      choices = LETTERS,
      selected = c("A", "B", "C")
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks I used a global variable. 

> values <- reactiveValues() 
> values$load_flag = FALSE

And check this flag every time but do the action only once.

Comment: @ShamitBagchi  Can you please elaborate your solution a little more and perhaps write a full answer to your own question, thereby allowing  others to use it. Thanks.